# How to train transfer-learning model on custom dataset? ValueError: Shape must be rank 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a transfer learning model to classify images. The images are a gray-scale (2D). previously I used `image_dataset_from_directory` method to read the images and there was no problem. However, I am trying to use a custom read function to have more control and access on the data such as knowing how many images in each class. When using this custom read function, I get an error (down below) while trying to train the model. I am not sure about what caused this error.

part1: reading the dataset

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras

# neural network
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing

IMG_WIDTH=160
IMG_HEIGHT=160

DATA_PATH = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\chest_xray"
TRAIN_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, 'train')

def create_dataset(img_folder):
   
    img_data_array=[]
    class_name=[]
   
    for dir1 in os.listdir(img_folder):
        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(img_folder, dir1)):
       
            image_path= os.path.join(img_folder, dir1,  file)
            image= cv2.imread( image_path, 0)
            image=cv2.resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            image=np.array(image)
            image = image.astype('float32')
            image /= 255 
            img_data_array.append(image)
            class_name.append(dir1)
    return img_data_array, class_name
# extract the image array and class name
img_data, class_name =create_dataset(TRAIN_DIR)
target_dict={k: v for v, k in enumerate(np.unique(class_name))}
target_dict


target_val=  [target_dict[class_name[i]] for i in range(len(class_name))]
```

this part will produce A list that has a size of 5232. inside the list there are numpy arrays of size 160X160 (float 32)

part 2: creating the model

```
def  build_model():

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(160, 160, 3))
    
    x = Sequential(
    [
        preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=0.15),
        preprocessing.RandomTranslation(height_factor=0.1, width_factor=0.1),
        preprocessing.RandomFlip(),
        preprocessing.RandomContrast(factor=0.1),
    ],
    name="img_augmentation",
    )(inputs)
    # x = img_augmentation(inputs)

    model=tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB7(include_top=False, 
                                               drop_connect_rate=0.4,
                                               weights='imagenet',
                                               input_tensor=x)
    # Freeze the pretrained weights
    model.trainable = False
    
    # Rebuild top
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool")(model.output)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    
    top_dropout_rate = 0.2
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(top_dropout_rate, name="top_dropout")(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="pred")(x)
    
    # Compile
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="EfficientNet")
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, 
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    
    return model


model = build_model()
```

part 3: train the model

```
history = model.fit(x=np.array(img_data), y=np.array(target_val), epochs=5)
```

---

the error I get:

```
 ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for '{{node 
EfficientNet/img_augmentation/random_rotation_1/transform/ImageProjectiveTransformV3}} = 
ImageProjectiveTransformV3[dtype=DT_FLOAT, fill_mode="REFLECT", interpolation="BILINEAR"]
(IteratorGetNext, EfficientNet/img_augmentation/random_rotation_1/rotation_matrix/concat, 
EfficientNet/img_augmentation/random_rotation_1/transform/strided_slice, 
EfficientNet/img_augmentation/random_rotation_1/transform/fill_value)' with input shapes: 
[?,160,160], [?,8], [2], [].
```

Comment: See my answer below, likely to have solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the code is that OpenCV reads the image in grayscale format, but the grayscale format of the image returned is not `(160,160,1)` but `(160,160)`.

Because of this fact, the error is thrown.

I managed to replicate your problem by testing it locally.

Say we randomly train on `12` samples.

Possible input formats:

```
 #This one works
 1. history = model.fit(x=np.random.rand(12,160,160,3), y=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]), epochs=5,verbose=1) WORKS
 #This one works
 2. history = model.fit(x=np.random.rand(12,160,160,1),  y=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]), epochs=5,verbose=1) WORKS
 #This one fails
 3. history = model.fit(x=np.random.rand(12,160,160), y=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]), epochs=5,verbose=1) FAILS
```

(1) and (2) work.

(3) fails, yielding:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for '{{node
> EfficientNet/img_augmentation/random_rotation_4/transform/ImageProjectiveTransformV2}} = ImageProjectiveTransformV2[dtype=DT_FLOAT, fill_mode="REFLECT", interpolation="BILINEAR"](IteratorGetNext,
> EfficientNet/img_augmentation/random_rotation_4/rotation_matrix/concat,
> EfficientNet/img_augmentation/random_rotation_4/transform/strided_slice)'
> with input shapes: [?,160,160], [?,8], [2].

Therefore, ensure that your data format is in the shape `(160,160,1)` or `(160,160,3)`.

As an alternative, after you you read the image with OpenCV, you can use

`image = np.expand_dims(image,axis=-1)`

to programatically insert the last axis (the grayscale).

Comment: thanks you very much for this insightful answer. I have added "image = np.expand_dims(image,axis=-1)" and it solved the problem. however, I got a warning that the model accept input as (None, 160, 160, 3) but (None, 160, 160, 1) is given; it shoudn't be a problem I guess.

Comment: Yes of course, you can then change the input shape to (160,160,1) instead of (160,160,3)